# How to start & travel in AnimationTree using code?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to animate an expandable staff by travel between nodes in `AnimationTree` Like this:

```
...
tool

export(String,"small", "mid", "full") var staff_mode = "small" setget set_staff_mode;

func set_staff_mode(new_val):
    
    var ani_state;
    if(self.has_node("/path/to/AnimationTree")):
        ani_state=self.get_node("/path/to/AnimationTree")["parameters/playback"];
        ani_state.start(staff_mode);
        print(ani_state.is_playing());
        ani_state.travel(new_val);
        ani_state.stop();
        
    staff_mode=new_val;
```

[image]

I haven't applied autoplay to `small` because I don't want a looping animation on the staff
(it only expands or compresses, no idle animation)

but for some reason it gives the error:

> Can't travel to 'full' if state machine is not playing. Maybe you
> need to enable Autoplay on Load for one of the nodes in your state
> machine or call .start() first?

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention but I don't have any idle animation for my staff so I need to stop the animation after the transition is complete.

small, mid & full
(all of them are static modes of the staff depending upon the game how much the staff should extend)
are all 0.1sec single frame animations and I applied Xfade Time of 0.2 secs to show the transition

I simply need to transition from an existing animation state to another and then stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### New Answer

Apparently the solution on the old answer does not work for very short animations. And the workarounds begin to seem to much overhead for my taste. So, as alternative, let us get rid of the `AnimationTree` and work directly with `AnimationPlayer`. To do this, we will:

1. Increase the animation duration to be long enough for the "cross fade" time (e.g. 0.2 seconds).
2. Put the "cross fade" time in "Cross-Animation Blend Times". For each animation, select it on the Animation panel and then select "Edit Transition…" from the animation menu, that opens the "Cross-Animation Blend Times" where you can specify the transition time to the other animations (e.g. 0 to itself, 0.1 to "adjacent" animation, and so on).

Now we can simply ask the `AnimationPlayer` to play, something like this:

```
tool
extends Node2D

enum Modes {full, mid, small}
export(Modes) var staff_mode setget set_staff_mode

func set_staff_mode(new_val:int) -> void:
    if staff_mode == new_val:
        return

    if not is_inside_tree():
        return

    var animation_player := get_node("AnimationPlayer") as AnimationPlayer
    if not is_instance_valid(animation_player):
        return

    var target_animation:String = Modes.keys()[new_val]
    animation_player.play(target_animation)
    yield(animation_player, "animation_finished")
    staff_mode = new_val
    property_list_changed_notify()
```

I have opted to use an enum, because this will also allow me to "travel" between the animations. The idea is that we will make a for loop where we call the animations in order. Like this:

```
tool
extends Node2D

enum Modes {full, mid, small}
export(Modes) var staff_mode:int setget set_staff_mode

func set_staff_mode(new_val:int) -> void:
    if staff_mode == new_val:
        return

    if not is_inside_tree():
        return

    var animation_player := get_node("AnimationPlayer") as AnimationPlayer
    if not is_instance_valid(animation_player):
        return

    var old_val := staff_mode
    staff_mode = new_val
    var travel_direction = sign(new_val - old_val)
    for mode in range(old_val, new_val + travel_direction, travel_direction):
        var target_animation:String = Modes.keys()[mode]
        animation_player.play(target_animation)
        yield(animation_player, "animation_finished")
```

I have also decided to set `staff_mode` early so I can avoid `property_list_changed_notify`.

*Concurrent calls may result in animation stopping early, since calling `play` stops the currently playing animation to play the new one. However, I don't think waiting for the current animation to end is correct. Also with so short animations, it should not be a problem.*

---

### Version using Tween

Using `Tween` will give you finer control, but it is also more work, because we are going to encode the animations in code… Which I will be doing with `interpolate_property`. Thankfully this is a fairly simple animation, so can manage without making the code too long.

Of course, you need to add a `Tween` node. We will not use `AnimationPlayer` nor `AnimationTree`. `Tween` will handle the interpolations (and you can even specify how to do the interpolations by adding the optional parameters of `interpolate_property`, which I'm not passing here).

This is the code:

```
tool
extends Node2D

enum Modes {full, mid, small}
export(Modes) var staff_mode:int setget set_staff_mode

func set_staff_mode(new_val:int) -> void:
    if staff_mode == new_val:
        return

    if not is_inside_tree():
        return

    var tween := get_node("Tween") as Tween
    if not is_instance_valid(tween):
        return

    var old_val := staff_mode
    staff_mode = new_val
    var travel_direction = sign(new_val - old_val)
    for mode in range(old_val, new_val + travel_direction, travel_direction):
        match mode:
            Modes.full:
                tween.interpolate_property($"1", "position", $"1".position, Vector2.ZERO, 0.2)
                tween.interpolate_property($"1/2", "position", $"1/2".position, Vector2(0, -35), 0.2)
                tween.interpolate_property($"1/2/3", "position", $"1/2/3".position, Vector2(0, -34), 0.2)
            Modes.mid:
                tween.interpolate_property($"1", "position", $"1".position, Vector2.ZERO, 0.2)
                tween.interpolate_property($"1/2", "position", $"1/2".position, Vector2(0, -35), 0.2)
                tween.interpolate_property($"1/2/3", "position", $"1/2/3".position, Vector2.ZERO, 0.2)
            Modes.small:
                tween.interpolate_property($"1", "position", $"1".position, Vector2.ZERO, 0.2)
                tween.interpolate_property($"1/2", "position", $"1/2".position, Vector2.ZERO, 0.2)
                tween.interpolate_property($"1/2/3", "position", $"1/2/3".position, Vector2.ZERO, 0.2)

        tween.start()
        yield(tween, "tween_all_completed")
```

What you can see here is that I have encoded the values from the tracks of from the `AnimationPlayer` in the source code. Using `Tween` I get to tell it to interpolate from whatever value the track has to the target position of each state.

*I don't know if this performs better or worse compared to `AnimationPlayer`.*

---

### Old Answer

Alright, there are two sides to this problem:

- `travel` is supposed to play the animation, so it is not instantaneous. Thus, if you call `stop` it will not be able to travel, and you get the error message you got.
- Ah, but you cannot call start and travel back to back either. You need to wait the animation to start.

---

I'll start by not going from one state to the same:

```
func set_staff_mode(new_val:String) -> void:
    if staff_mode == new_val:
        return
```

---

We are going to need to get the `AnimationTree`, so we need to ge in the scene tree. Here I use `yield` so the method returns, and Godot resumes the execute after it gets the `"tree_entered"` signal:

```
    if not is_inside_tree():
        yield(self, "tree_entered")
```

The drawback of `yield`, is that it can cause an error if the `Node` is free before you get the signal. Thus, if you prefer to not use `yield`, we can do this instead:

```
    if not is_inside_tree():
        # warning-ignore:return_value_discarded
        connect("tree_entered", self, "set_staff_mode", [new_val], CONNECT_ONESHOT)
        return
```

Here `CONNECT_ONESHOT` ensures this signal is automatically disconnected. Also, Godot makes sure to disconnect any signals when freeing a `Node` so this does not have the same issue as `yield`. However, unlike `yield` it will not start in the middle of the method, instead it will call the method again.

---

Alright, we get the `AnimationTree`:

```
var animation_tree := get_node("/path/to/AnimationTree")
if not is_instance_valid(animation_tree):
    return
```

And get the `AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback`:

```
var ani_state:AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback = animation_tree.get("parameters/playback")
```

---

Now, if it is not playing, we need to make it playing:

```
    if not ani_state.is_playing():
        ani_state.start(new_val)
```

---

And now the problem: we need to wait for the animation to start.

In lieu of a better solution, we going to pool for it:

```
        while not ani_state.is_playing():
            yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
```

*Previously I was suggesting to get the `AnimationPlayer` so we can wait for `"animation_started"`, but that does not work.*

---

Finally, now that we know it is playing, we can use `travel`, and update the state:

```
    ani_state.travel(new_val)
    staff_mode = new_val
```

*Don't call `stop`.*

---

You might also want to call `property_list_changed_notify()` at the end, so Godot reads the new value of `staff_mode`, which it might not have registered because we didn't change it right away (instead we yielded before changing it).  *I suppose you could alternatively change the value earlier, before any `yield`.*

---

By the way, if you want the `mid` animation to complete in the `travel`, change the connections going out of `mid` in the `AnimationTree` from "Immidiate" to "AtEnd".

---

**Addendum on waiting for travel to end and stop**

We can spin wait in a similar fashion as we did to wait for the `AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback` to start playing. This time we need to pool two things:

- What is the current state of the animation.
- What is the playback position on that animation.

As long as the animation is not in the final state and as long as it has not reached the end of that animation, we let one frame pass and check again. Like this:

```
    while (
        ani_state.get_current_node() != new_val
        or ani_state.get_current_play_position() < ani_state.get_current_length()
    ):
        yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
```

Then you can call `stop`.

---

Furthermore, I'll add a check for `is_playing`. The reason is that this code is waiting for the `AnimationTree` to complete the state we told it to… But if you call travel again before it finished, it will go to new destination, and thus might never reach the state we expected, which result in spin waiting for ever.

And since it might not have arrived to the state we expected, I decided to query the final state instead of setting `staff_mode` to `new_val`. That part of the code now looks like this:

```
    ani_state.travel(new_val)
    while (
        ani_state.is_playing() and (
            ani_state.get_current_node() != new_val
            or ani_state.get_current_play_position()
               < ani_state.get_current_length()
        )
    ):
        yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")

    ani_state.stop()
    staff_mode = ani_state.get_current_node()
    property_list_changed_notify()
```

Comment: I tried [the code](https://justpaste.it/9kx4n) but it's getting stuck at `yield(animation_player, "animation_started")` also I've made an edit to the question to make sure this doesn't become an xy problem

Comment: @cakelover I can confirm. I had not noticed it was getting stuck there. The workaround I found is pool for `is_playing`, I have updated the answer.

Comment: now it works, but how do I stop the animation after the travel is complete? like I mentioned in the edit, I don't have an idle animation and since it's a 0.1sec single frame animation it takes up to much power and everything becomes jittery & laggy

Comment: @cakelover see addendum.

Comment: for some reason, I had to add this [extra segment of code](https://justpaste.it/9dpt5) for it to work. If I don't, the animation gets stopped midway of completion, I'm guessing the yield doesn't give enough time to complete the animation?

Comment: by midway I meant to say a few frames before completion

Comment: @cakelover It works correctly for me. I tried changing animation duration, cross fade and process modes, but I didn't get the behavior you describe.

Comment: I've created a [sample project](https://ufile.io/0i5ql0rh) this seems to replicate the error with bare minimum

Comment: @cakelover It appears to be a bug. If I increase the duration of the animations to 0.2 it seems to work correctly, so I'm guessing it is not accounting for cross fade. You may want to report that to https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues - For now I'm thinking that perhaps you can archive the same effect with `Tween`s.

Comment: could you add a tween example to your answer so I can mark as solved? and btw which would be more effective and less memory consuming between `tweens` or `AnimationPlayer`?

Comment: [permanent link](https://ufile.io/kutgmgdh) for above sample project for future reference (Godot v3.4 stable mono)